# How to conditionally change class inheritance at compile-time in Delphi??

Tags: delphi

I'm working on a Delphi project where I have a specific set of classes defined, such as:

```
TClassA = class(TObject)
...
TClassB = class(TObject)
...
TMyClass = class(TClassA)
...
```

I have a requirement where, based on certain conditions that are determined at compile time, I want TMyClass to instead inherit from TClassB.

Essentially, I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
{$IFDEF SOME_COMPILE_TIME_CONDITION}
TMyClass = class(TClassB)
{$ELSE}
TMyClass = class(TClassA)
{$ENDIF}
```

Is it possible in Delphi to conditionally define the parent class of TMyClass at compile time? If so, how can I achieve this? If not, are there any workarounds or alternative approaches you can suggest?

Comment: You can do it - you just presented an example how to do it. You can define `SOME_COMPILE_TIME_CONDITION` in the project options, in an *.inc file or even in the unit itself, depending on your needs.

Comment: yes was just curious if their is no other solutions more elegant

Comment: You can even inject project-wide defines into the MSBuild command line if you want. Maybe that's more elegant. :-)

Comment: If you want parent class of your `TMyClass` to have different functionality based on [Conditional compilation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)) you don't even need to have two separate parent classes but instead one class with specific conditional compilation code sections. Take a look at source code that ships with Delphi. It is filled with various conditional compilation code sections. Especially in libraries that are not strictly dependent on VCL or FMX frameworks.

Comment: This is a bad idea. What is your real problem? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @JanDoggen hard to explain in comment why i want to do this. I have a base project with thoses 3 classes TA<=TB<=TC and in an other project I must override only TA so that TB and TC uses the new behavior. so what a want to do in the another project is TA<=TCustomTA<=TB<=TC

Comment: I think you want to create a Factory class (lookup Factory Pattern) that you call to get the object you want at run time and not worry about what's being compiled. The compilation process imposes its own limitations on things that have nothing to do with the language, and you're trying to pretend they're related. This might be accomplished directly with a Factory class, and it might require some Dependency Injection. But solving it using conditional compiles is the most brittle and convoluted way to do it. I suggest you rethink your approach.

Comment: I highly recommend this book:

https://codingindelphi.com/diindelphi.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this qualifies for *more elegant*, but you might have difficulties to find anything else anyway:

```
{$IFDEF SOME_COMPILE_TIME_CONDITION}
TMyParentClass = TClassB
{$ELSE}
TMyParentClass = TClassA
{$ENDIF}

TMyClass = class(TMyParentClass)
```

Comment: I try with include and unfortunatly it's not working because of this delphi bug : https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-42021

Comment: finally I will not accept the answer because it's not work either with the {$IFDEF} :( 
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-42021

Comment: While the compiler should be fine with it, the problems come when these classes are to be loaded in the IDE designer. If you had mentioned that in the question I would probably not have given the answer without verifying that it actually works in that case.

Comment: no problem, you answer was very fine, it's just a delphi bug that break it :(

Answer (score 2):

This might be a little off, depending on what you're trying to do, but based on the information I have I'd solve this problem using an interface.

pseudocode...

```
type
  TMyClass = class( TMyBaseClass ); 
    
  TMyBaseClass = class
  private
    fImplementation: IMyImplementation;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;
    
constructor TMyBaseClass.Create;
begin
  {$ifdef CONDA}
  fImplementation := TCondAImplementation.Create;
  {$else}
  fImplementation := TCondBImplementation.Create;
  {$end}
end;
```

Your descendant can then either call protected methods of the base class which call on the differing implementations, OR provide protected access to the fImplementation member directly.